# Python function that only has print output?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function in python that outputs a menu like this:

#### MENU

p) Play the matching penny game

q) Quit

What I've tried...

```
def display_menu():
    print "###MENU###"
    print "p) Play the matching penny game"
    print "q) Quit"
```

I want to call the function in a script and have the menu displayed, but it doesn't display in the shell nor does it throw an error. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: as long as you call the function `>>> display_menu()` it should work.

Comment: Show us your script, to see how did you call a function. I am afraid there is typo.

Comment: This is very basic stuff that is covered in any decent python tutorial. You are better off just slugging through a tutorial than letting yourself get bogged down trying to write code too early.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to call the display_menu function. Try this:

```
def display_menu():
    print "MENU".center(10, "#")
    print "p) Play the matching penny game"
    print "q) Quit"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    display_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def display_menu():
    print "###MENU###"
    print "p) Play the matching penny game"
    print "q) Quit"

display_menu()    # call the function
```

You have to actually call the function in order for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need parentheses around your text..

```
def display_menu():
    print ("###MENU###")
    print ("p) Play the matching penny game")
    print ("q) Quit")
display_menu()
```

Comment: This was my problem, I'm new to python hahah - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The function you wrote is 100% fine for what you want. The problem is that you aren't calling it at all during execution. If your program is going to be complex, I'd suggest creating a `main` function where everything major takes place, the heart of your program, and calling that via:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Otherwise you can have it called however you want, as long it the function is executed at runtime, which it currently isn't.